# Redirecting @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser) if not a superuser to another page

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect, python-3.x

This is an extension on a previous question. I got the authentication working with `is_superuser` and `is_staff`. Now if a staff is logged in and wants to view something only the superuser can view, I want it to redirect to a different page. Do I modify `@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)` to redirect the staff member to another page? If so, How do I do that?

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from ManagerApp import models as pmod
from . import templater
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@login_required(login_url='/ManagerApp/login/')
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

def process_request__new(request):
  q = pmod.User()
  q.first_name = 'New User!'
  q.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('/ManagerApp/edit_user/' + str(q.id))

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

def process_request(request):
  '''Shows all users in the DB'''
  q = pmod.User.objects.get(id=request.urlparams[0])
  form = UserForm(initial={
    #'active': q.is_active,
    'superuser': q.is_superuser,
    'staff': q.is_staff,
    'firstname': q.first_name,
    'lastname': q.last_name,
    'username': q.username,
    'password': q.password,
    'email': q.email,
    'street': q.street,
    'city': q.city,
    'state': q.state,
    'zipCode': q.zipcode,
    'phone': q.phone,
  })
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      #q.is_active = form.cleaned_data['active']
      q.is_superuser = form.cleaned_data['superuser']
      q.is_staff = form.cleaned_data['staff']
      q.first_name = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
      q.last_name = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
      q.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
      q.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
      q.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
      q.street = form.cleaned_data['street']
      q.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
      q.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
      q.zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
      q.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
      q.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/ManagerApp/users/')

  # return the template html
  template_vars = {
    'form': form,
  }
  return templater.render_to_response(request, 'edit_user.html', template_vars)

class UserForm(forms.Form):
  '''The question form'''
  #active = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  superuser = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  staff = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
  firstname = forms.CharField(required=False)
  lastname = forms.CharField(required=False)
  username = forms.CharField(required=False)
  password = forms.CharField(required=False)
  email = forms.CharField(required=False)
  street = forms.CharField(required=False)
  city = forms.CharField(required=False)
  state = forms.CharField(required=False)
  zipcode = forms.CharField(required=False)
  phone = forms.CharField(required=
```

False)

Answer (score 4):

Directly from the docs:

> [`user_passes_test()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) takes an optional `login_url` argument, which lets you specify the URL for your login page (settings.LOGIN_URL by default).

Obviously, you don't have to send them to a login page. eg:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser, login_url='/get-outta-here/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

---

What I'll write below here isn't direct related to your question, but is intended as further advice.

I think you should look at Django's [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) and [class-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/). You could end up writing a lot less code. By the looks of it you could write most of your view with simply:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['list', 'of', 'all', 'your', 'field', 'names']

class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
```

(Of course, then you would need to look into [decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)...)